# ASP.NET MVC: Does Html.EditorForModel support built-in override some specific field without whole model template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I'm searching a solution for ASP.NET MVC views development. Does `Html.EditorForModel` (or `DisplayForModel`) support built-in helper that allow us to override some specific field without whole model template?

Example:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(model => model.Customer)
    .Override(customer => customer.FullName, (data, meta) => {
        return "<span class="highlight">@data</span>";
    }).Override(customer => customer.Star, (data, meta) => {
        return "@Html.DropdownFor(data, ViewBag.Stars)";
    })
```

Comment: Not out of the box, but its not clear what your trying to do with this. Why not create your own `EditorTemplate`?

Comment: Hello, I have a lot of models/viewmodels which had a lot of properties to manipulate (>30). So I build some generic EditorTemplate, DisplayTemplate. But in some case, I need to customize the template and I don't want to duplicate code too much. It's similar that overriding a few base method in OOP concept.

Comment: So do I, but what are your wanting to achieve - what would `.Override(customer => customer.FullName, ...` actually do?

Comment: oh, Override extension in my example mean apply the explicit template/render for specific field of model.

Comment: You can apply a `[UIHint("MyTemplate")]` attribute to the property and add an `EditorTemplate` for `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyTemplate.cshtml`